# Can I say “I hope I can get any chance to go back”?

Tags: grammaticality

My friend said, “Can’t wait for you to come back.”

Can I say:

> I hope I can get any chance to go back.

Or

> If only I can get any chance to go back.

Or

> I hope I will get a chance.

Do they sound okay ?

Comment: ***Any*** is a "negative polarity" item, which means it requires a "negating" context, such as *I **don't** have **any** chance of going*. What you need is the plain article with ***will***, not ***can*** - for example: *I hope I **will** get **a** chance to go back.* But this is just proofreading / personal preference.

Comment: Thank you very much!:) I wonder if it’s too formal. Is it okay to write it as a comment?

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  What do you think the answer might be?  (Use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the “[Contributor’s Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)” and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!